# How to browse unc directories using command prompt

Tags: windows, networking

i was trying to change my change directory in my unc path,while trying to access the network folder myself getting error :

```
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

is it there any method to access unc directories through command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Which is annoying in this day of networked-everything.

[Powershell](http://ss64.com/ps/) is the next best thing if you want something native to Windows 7 or higher, without installing 3rd party tools. It generally copes with UNC paths fine.

Alternatively, you can [map a UNC path to a drive letter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive#1TC=windows-7). Then you can happily use the command prompt against that drive letter.